# Excel 2003: Why does creating links to other spreadsheets take so long?

Tags: performance, excel, vba, hyperlink

My Excel application creates links to other Excel files. It takes approx 1 sec to create a link for 1 cell, but I have several hundred cells to link so it's painfully slow.
There is no difference in speed whether the source file is opened or closed. I have, however, noticed that creating links manually (e.g., by copying and pasting the formula containing the link into other cells by hand) is much faster while the source file is opened.

In my program I have configured
Application.Calculation to be Manual instead of Automatic.

I tried accomplish the linking in two ways (please note this is not a real code, but I hope it shows what I mean):

1.
Copy the formula link to the external source from `Range("A1")` using
a foreach loop on every `Cell` in a range:

`Cell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1").FormulaR1C1`

2.
Copy the formula from `Range("A1")` to another range without using a foreach loop:

`Range("thisIsMyTargetRange").FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1").FormulaR1C1`

Both methods are equally slow, and as I said I've checked both of the above methods with the source file opened *and* closed.

Is there any way to speed this up? Does anyone know enough about the linking mechanism in Excel 2003 to offer advice on how to improve the linking performance?

Comment: I suspect the lag is because it is checking the file system for each link, and that is creating the overhead. Try opening the target workbook(s) before creating the links.

Comment: I'm not familiar with linking workbooks, but perhaps Screen Updating option may be the key: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/screen-updating.shtml

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2003 files are XML files, specifically SpreadsheetML. If you are brave enough and willing to learn (and screw up a few files on the way) you can manipiulate the XML directly without opening Excel - no updates until you open the revised file in excel.

Comment: @DaleM I thought Office XML didn't arrive until Excel 2007?

Comment: Could it simply be all the disk I/O?  You said it is faster when the workbook your referencing is already open.  If its open that means its in memory so there is no disk I/O for that file.  If I'm right then buying an SSD (I'm assuming you're on a platter HDD) and keeping your excel files on it should help.  On another note it seems you'd be much better suited moving all your data to a database  (ex. SQL, Access) than storing it in many different excel files.

Comment: One way to test my theory would be to setup a RAMdrive and copy your files to it.  Then you could open your master file leaving all the other files closed and see if the references to files on your RAMdrive give you a noticeable improvement.  If it does then you may consider buying the SSD.  If there is no improvement then your problem isn't disk IO and the only performance gain I could offer would be to move to a database solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it pertinent to have the formulas? If not use `.value` instead of `.formular1c1`.

Also if the ranges are the same size then use a range copy instead of the loop. e.g.

```
range(a1:a500).value = range(a1:a500)
```

**Added Alternative Method:**

Also, an alternative method would be to create a table using the data import functionthat is refreshed when the file opens, if a sheet is what you after. Then if you wanted bits of that sheet, use the data in the import sheet/table. This will keep the updating or linking to only **one** large import when opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for months of data taken around once a second.

Open the document you want to copy data from.  Then copy any sheets that hold that data into the workbook you are using.  Grab the data from them, then delete those sheets from your workbook.  Do this in a macro so it can be done quickly and repeatedly.